# OCR with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to read info from an ID card using OCR in my Xamarin Forms app, but the only example I find is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Tesseract/) and it's pretty outdated (or I just don't know how to use it).

I also saw the Google Vision AI, which I could use in my Xamarin.Android (or iOS) and pass the information to my shared project, but I can't imagine how I would do that.

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Comment: first hit in google - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/performing-ocr-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, you solved it, please share your solution to answer.

Comment: No, because the Oxford Vision isn't supported anymore and I want something open source, but I'm trying to use the Xamarin.Tesseract nuget I found. However, I'm not yet done implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

check this link. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/performing-ocr-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/

sample app app to track invoices using Microsoft Cognitive Services and Xamarin - https://github.com/pierceboggan/smarter-apps

code sample -

```
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;
...
OcrResults text;
var client = new VisionServiceClient("{YOUR-API-KEY-HERE}");
using (var photoStream = photo.GetStream())
{
    text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(photoStream);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Xamarin wrapper for Google's Teseract you could use:
https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin