# How to convert Camera captured image to Scanned image in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need a Xamarin iOS code to convert image to scanned image, or I need a code to scan a image( eg: ID card, Passport) using camera option for better resolution.

how to achieve this using Xamarin iOS?

Comment: You need to give a much better explanation of what you mean by a "scanned image".

Comment: i need a option to scan documents like license/passport instead of capturing it for better resolution and clarity. Is there a way to do that? or is there a possible way to convert already captured image to Scanned document eg:scanning a barcode, likewise I need to scan a Image not barcode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OCR with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316488/ocr-with-xamarin)

Comment: Thanks @Jason, but I need code in Xamarin.iOS (native) not Xamarin.Forms

Comment: The actual OCR work is done in Azure - you can easily modify the samples provided to work with iOS or Android.

Comment: And I don't need to extract the data from Image , I just need to scan and store the image

Comment: That’s why I asked you to explain what you meant by “scanned image”.  There is no functional difference between “capture” and “scan” when you are using the device camera.